# Why is my django Translation not working?

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have a form where most elements are translating as I would expect but a the language dropdown isn't.

I have a file, `languages.py` of the following format:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGE_OPTIONS = (
    ("Abkhaz", "аҧсуа (%s)" % _("Abkhaz")),
    ("Afar", "Afaraf (%s)" %  _("Afar")),
    ("Afrikaans", "Afrikaans (%s)" %  _("Afrikaans")),
    ("Akan", "Akan (%s)" %  _("Akan")),
    ("Albanian", "Shqip (%s)" %  _("Albanian")),
    ....
    ("Zhuang, Chuang", "Saɯ cueŋƅ, Saw cuengh (%s)" %  _("Zhuang, Chuang")),
)
```

The idea being the English version of the code is saved to the database but the user can see the language in it's original and their language.

I import this into `forms.py` using `from .languages import LANGUAGE_OPTIONS as language_choices`

I then have the following field within the form

```
other_languages = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                 choices=language_choices, 
                 label = _("Which language(s)"), required = False
            )
```

"Which language(s)" is translated correctly, but the languages within the choices are not.

What have I got wrong?

**EDIT**
I think I might know the answer but if anyone can confirm I would appreciate it.

I think `LANGUAGE_OPTIONS` should be setup as

```
LANGUAGE_OPTIONS = (
    ("Abkhaz", _("аҧсуа (Abkhaz)"),
    ...
)
```

And then in django.po my translation would look like

```
msgid "аҧсуа (Abkhaz)"
msgstr "аҧсуа (abkhaz)"
```

Is that right?

Comment: That's what I would do also `("Abkhaz", _("аҧсуа (Abkhaz)"),`. Does it work???

Comment: Yes, it works as per edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LANGUAGE_OPTIONS should be setup as

```
LANGUAGE_OPTIONS = (
    ("Abkhaz", _("аҧсуа (Abkhaz)"),
    ...
)
```

And then in django.po my translation would look like

```
msgid "аҧсуа (Abkhaz)"
msgstr "аҧсуа (abkhaz)"
```